# Firebase error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pieceNum_')

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

Error:

[image: error image]

I don't know what is the problem why am i getting this error?

```
function downloa2323d() {
    console.log("Trying to download")
    get(child(database, `design-tournament/`)).then((snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          let jsonData = snapshot.val();
          function download(content, fileName, contentType) {
            const a = document.createElement("a");
            const file = new Blob([content], { type: "application/json" });
            a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            a.download = fileName;
            a.click();
          }
  
          function onDownload(){
            console.log(jsonData)
              download(jsonData, "design-tournament-game.json", "text/plain");
          }

          onDownload()
        } else {
          console.log("No data available");
        }
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
}

document.getElementById("exportGame").addEventListener('click', downloa2323d )
```

The error line: 745 is the get child database from firebase in the code

```
import { getDatabase, ref, child, get, push, update, onValue } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.0.0/firebase-database.js";

const app2 = initializeApp(firebaseConfig2, "server");
const database = getDatabase(app2);
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show how `database` is initialized?

Comment: I fixed it! I forgot to add a ref(). I noticed after reading docs

Comment: Good to hear. Can you post it as a full answer, so that the system knows your problem has been solved and so that others who land here in the future are more likely to find what worked for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! I forgot to add a ref(). I noticed after reading docs

Maybe if you have this problem try adding ref( database ) instead of just database